# VB.net login error not handled in user code

Tags: vb.net

Having below error when running my code in vs :
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot open database "Parking.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.

On page below is being displayed : 
Server Error in '/' Application.

Cannot open database "Parking.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\rooma.sti@outlook.com'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "Parking.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\rooma.sti@outlook.com'.

Please find code below :

**

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection("data source=LAPTOP-IL991RVO\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Parking.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()
```

**

I'm new to this, have i missed out on anything 
Please help
Cheers !

Comment: initial catalog=Parking -- check if it is attached or not (no .mdf)

Comment: one more if you use integrated security=true then sql should have both windows & sql login enabled .... or just provide user name and password in connection string

Comment: thanks for your reply. just added the below -   Dim con As New SqlConnection("data source=LAPTOP-IL991RVO\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Parking;Trusted_Connection=Yes;User ID=Rooma ;Password=******;") still same :-(

Comment: it works!!! i added the path of the mdf location ! thanks for your help anyway :-)